# Can a login page be configured to target specific user

Tags: malware

Can a website be configured to only download malware onto a system if a specific user logs in.

Comment: I suggest to rephrase your question. If you want to attack specific users I doubt this is the place to get your information from.

Comment: Jason - this is not a question about security. Your question is simply around carrying out actions based on specific logon. Basic programming question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are somehow in control of the login site you can of course do it. Such "in control" might be if you legally own the site, illegally own it (i.e. hacked) or can control the relevant part of it with Cross-Site-Scripting attacks or maybe because you've compromised the database with SQL injection (to have just a selection of possible attacks). You might also do it if you don't have control of the site itself but are in control of a system in the path (i.e. a reverse proxy or load balancer, router...) and can mount a man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After a specified user logs into the system, a webscript usually JavaScript can be used at client (browser) that can easily initiate a download.